# CarrierWave Resize Image doesn't show ups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

When I upload and register, the image comes out to cover the whole page. When I tried to change the image settings by following the Carrierwave instructions to use the thumb, the new page shows only the text, Thumb_picture_5. and no image.

Here is the terminal error:

```
Started GET "/uploads/bar/image/1/thumb_picture_5.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jul 26 11:59:25 -0400    2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/uploads/bar/image/1/thumb_picture_5.png"):
```

Comment: Can you show your config file, the one auto-generated by carrierwave (under app/uploaders) ?